# IOS JSON versus ASPNET Web services

Tags: .net, ios, vb.net, ios5

Can anyone please help me? I am stucking this problem for long time.

I am developing an IOS which to throw JSON to web service in order to insert into database.
But failed to do it.

**IOS Source Code**

```
-(IBAction)signup{

    NSMutableDictionary * dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dic setObject:@"0" forKey:@"account_id"];
    [dic setObject:@"Jin" forKey:@"first_name"];
    [dic setObject:@"Lim" forKey:@"last_name"];
    [dic setObject:@"1987-12-02" forKey:@"date_of_birth"];
    [dic setObject:@"M" forKey:@"account_gender"];
    [dic setObject:@"65" forKey:@"phone_country_id"];
    [dic setObject:@"123456" forKey:@"account_phone"];
    [dic setObject:@"jin@test.biz" forKey:@"account_login"];

    [svc execMethod:dic];  
}
```

and then

```
-(void) execMethod:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic{

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.biz/AccountInfo.asmx/insert_account"];

    //Request 
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    //prepare http body
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
```

**Web Service**

```
{WebMethod()} _
{ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)}_
Public Function insert_account(ByVal result As Account) As String

    Dim account As New Account
    account = result
    Dim msg As String

    **Processing Result***

    Return "msg:'OK'"

End Function
```

**P/S: I Used {} to replace >< for Webservice method**

**Error in NSLOG**

```
2012-02-02 16:25:11.433 test.biz[10642:f803] System.InvalidOperationException: insert_account Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Please kindly tell me what have i done wrongly, Thanks for help :)

Comment: can you access the web method from a browser?

Comment: also, what version of .net are you using?

Comment: Have you tested your web service? My guess is that you haven't properly configured the web service, either in the web.config file or with the annotations (such as `<WebMethod()>`). I'd put the XCode project aside for the moment, start up Fiddler, build a request there and test the web service with it.

Comment: Hi AnthonyBlake and Codo, thank for your reply. I able to access the web method from browser and i am using 3.5 .net. The attached Image is what i see when browse the web service, http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/screenshot20120202at909.png/ .Please kindly advice me if i am wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jin-Aurora: Thanks for the screen shot. It shows a full SOAP request and response. SOAP (based on XML) is something else than JSON, which doesn't use XML. You'll need to test with a JSON request. Possibly your service isn't JSON ready yet.

Comment: @Codo: But i tried to use jquery to pass JSON to the web service, it's success to process. Any advise how i amend it correctly?

Comment: @Jin-Aurora: If the web service works with jQuery, then you can easily record the request with Firebug or Fiddler. Please add the recorded request to your question and I can most likely tell you what you need to change.

Comment: @Codo, You mean record the request with Firebug or Fiddler for jQuery or IOS? Sorry for troubling you, because i still new for web service, jQuery and IOS >.<

Comment: @Jin-Aurora: Record what jQuery does. I guess it's a web application so it'll run in your browser. You don't need XCode / iOS for that step.

Comment: @Codo, Here is the request, http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/screenshot20120203at956.png/ I am apologize that cannot provide the actual hosting info, hope you can understand. Thanks for your help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
-(IBAction)signup{

    NSMutableDictionary * dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dic setObject:@"0" forKey:@"account_id"];
    [dic setObject:@"Jin" forKey:@"first_name"];
    [dic setObject:@"Lim" forKey:@"last_name"];
    [dic setObject:@"1987-12-02" forKey:@"date_of_birth"];
    [dic setObject:@"M" forKey:@"account_gender"];
    [dic setObject:@"65" forKey:@"phone_country_id"];
    [dic setObject:@"123456" forKey:@"account_phone"];
    [dic setObject:@"jin@test.biz" forKey:@"account_login"];

    NSMutableDictionary * result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [result setObject:dic forKey:@"result"];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.biz/AccountInfo.asmx/insert_account"];

    svc = [[JSONRPCService alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [svc execMethod:result];
}
```

Just need to add the header for the JSON.